# why can the terminal not find my executable

Tags: command-line, bash

Hey all i have been experimenting with make and Ubuntu 14.04 in order to automate the build

i have created 2 simple programs

test2.exe

test2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s","Built using make");
    return 0;
}
```

and test.exe

main.c

```
extern int print();

int _start()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

test.c

```
int print()
{
    printf("%s","Built using make");
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
print:
    gcc -Wall test.c -c -o test.o
    gcc -Wall main.c -c -o main.o
    ld -o test.exe test.o main.o -lc    
test:
    gcc -Wall test2.c -o test2.exe
```

the issue that i am experiencing is that the terminal cannot find test.exe with the command `./test.exe` but finds test2.exe fine with `./test2.exe`

the error it gives me is `bash: ./test.exe: No such file or directory`

when it is clearly there in the directory.

I am calling make print to build test.exe and make test to build test2.exe
why is this happening

**edit in response to the comments** the output of ls ld test.exe is

```
ls: cannot access ld: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access test.exe: No such file or directory
```

The output of `make print`

```
gcc -Wall test.c -c -o test.o
gcc -Wall main.c -c -o main.o
```

ld -o test.exe test.o main.o -lc
Ant the output of `make test`
    `gcc -Wall test.c -o test2.exe`**

screenshot of directory

[image]

Screenshot of ls output

[image]

`ls -q` output

[image]

Comment: Executables don't have an .exe extension in linux, just sayin'.

Comment: @Mahadi it doesn't work even without the .exe

Comment: Yeah I don't know the solution I just thought I have to say it.

Comment: Thanks anyway it has never happened to me before could it be a bug in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You've shown code under "test2.exe". What file is that in, and is it actually being used? How are you building `test2.exe`? For example, if you're issuing a `gcc` command directly in the terminal, what command are you using? And how exactly are you calling `make` (i.e., what command are you running, exactly)? And what is the complete and exact output of `make` (i.e., what do you see in the terminal)? This situation is confusing because `gcc -Wall test.c -o test2.exe` itself *shouldn't work* to build `test2.exe` (since `test.c` is the only input file of any kind and it contains no `main()`).

Comment: "main.c", "test.c", and "Makefile" are all individual files, correct? Also, if I am interpreting this correctly, "test.exe" is a folder that contains these files, correct?

Comment: @System.Object Important information is missing from this question, and I'm not sure a definitive answer is possible without it. In addition to providing the information requested above, please run the commands [shown in this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76490/11938) (with `test.exe` in place of `xls`) and show us their output too. Please [edit] your question to include all this information. I suspect this may be similar to the problem there, but I'm not at all sure. Right now there's not enough information to clarify what you've done, what you expected, and what happened instead.

Comment: i added more info let me know if you need anything else

Comment: @mchid no test.exe is the executable

Comment: what about the output of only running the command `ls` in the directory containing the file.

Comment: it is there but here it is again `ls: cannot access ld: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access test.exe: No such file or directory`

Comment: @System.Object You have not yet provided most of the requested information (and you omitted the `-` that must immediately precede `ld`, i.e., it should be `ls -ld test.exe`). But some information may be gleaned from what you've given us so far. That `ls` reports `test.exe` doesn't exist suggests it really doesn't (and thus that this is perhaps not the same as [that problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76490/11938)). You said "it is clearly there in the directory." What do you mean by that? How do you know it is there?

Comment: See screenshots i added

Comment: @EliahKagan my bad, thanks I didn't know. use this command: `sudo find / -name "test.exe"` instead of `locate "test.exe"`.

Comment: @mchid My comment was flawed too: I didn't mean to say running `ls` by itself would be a bad thing to do, only that the simple output of a narrowly tailored command like `ls -ld test.exe` or `ls test.exe` is most helpful. (Thus it was only the "NO" part I should've disputed, not the *run `ls`* part.) [I think](http://askubuntu.com/a/531497) `ls` on `test.exe` revealed the problem: the filename likely contains non-printing control characters, producing the appearance of inconsistency between a full listing (in Nautilus, and from `ls`) and a query for a file with `test.exe` as the exact name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the file listing in Nautilus (or run `ls` with no arguments), it shows a file whose name *appears* to be `test.exe`.

But when you pass `test.exe` as an argument to `ls`, it does not find it, and outputs the error:

```
ls: cannot access test.exe: No such file or directory
```

The most probable explanation is that the file's name is displayed as `test.exe`, but that is not actually its name.

This can happen when a file's name [contains non-printing characters](http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?p=1692134). You can verify this hypothesis by running `ls -q`. If a file with one or more `?` is shown, whose name is otherwise similar to `test.exe`, that confirms the problem. If not, the problem likely has some other cause.

Since you have a graphical desktop and Nautilus displays the file, the easiest way to fix the problem is probably to rename it to `test.exe` in Nautilus.

In the file browser window, right-click the file whose name appears to be `test.exe`. Click "Rename..." to edit the filename. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire name, and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to clear it. (Or just start typing the new name and it will overwrite it.) Type `test.exe`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then try running your program again.

---

If that solved the problem, the question immediately arises as to *how* a non-printing character got into the filename. Since the filename was specified in `Makefile`, perhaps you accidentally pasted or otherwise entered input into your text editor containing a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

You can remove and replace `test.exe` in `Makefile` to fix the problem there.

<sub>If renaming the file in Nautilus did *not* solve the problem--or if `ls -q` didn't show any `?` characters--please edit your question to update it with detailed information about what did happen, and work on the problem can continue.</sub>

Comment: I tried renaming it and that did not work I have added a screenshot showing the ls -q output hope this helps